# Error:(72) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1'

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I'd like to know why I get this error at the first place, what is the solution and why it works? Your help is much appreciated.

My Gradle file is as below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 4
        versionName "4.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.d'
            versionNameSuffix '-debug'
        }
    }
}

ext {
    supportLibraryVersion = '24.2.1'
    junitVersion = '4.12'
    mockitoVersion = '1.10.19'
    hamcrestVersion = '1.3'
    espressoVersion = '2.2.2'
    runnerVersion = '0.5'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibraryVersion"

    testCompile "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-all:$mockitoVersion"
    testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:$hamcrestVersion"

    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:runner:$runnerVersion"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:rules:$runnerVersion"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espressoVersion"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$espressoVersion"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$espressoVersion"
    //androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:$espressoVersion"
    //androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:$espressoVersion"
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibraryVersion"
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportLibraryVersion"
    //resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
}

configurations.compile.dependencies.each { compileDependency ->
    println "Excluding compile dependency: ${compileDependency.getName()}"
    configurations.androidTestCompile.dependencies.each { androidTestCompileDependency ->
        configurations.androidTestCompile.exclude module: "${compileDependency.getName()}"
    }
}
```

The Errors that I get when do a build from Android Studio IDE are as below:

```
Error:(72) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1'.
Error:(75) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption'.
Error:(89) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button'.
Error:(97, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textAllCaps'.
Error:(102, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'elevation'.
Error:(113, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'backgroundTint'.
Error:(113, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'elevation'.
```

Comment: @cricket_007 You're right. Can you please pen your thoughts as answer so that I can accept it. Please explain how you went about this reasoning from the Android Docs, so I get a piece of your mind. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the android support design library

Try adding this

```
compile "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
```

Reason being that those are themes that you are missing. While I can't prove those are in-fact included in the design library, it would make sense that is where they come from.

And, if you do include that dependency, these lines aren't actually necessary.

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibraryVersion"
```

Comment: You're right. That said, my Espresso tests fail unless I add  `compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibraryVersion"
`. Wierd :-/

Comment: I think that's because of the bottom section with `configurations.all` and the one after that with the exclusions ... The Support Design library transitively includes those two, so I am not sure why there would be errors